# Remove-Item cmdlet causes "Cannot find path" while process of removal of .exe files in local folder

Tags: powershell

I have script that selects `.exe` files with the specified name from the local folder and removes all files, except first.

`$P` variable is defined in `param`.

`$P ="$($env:USERPROFILE)\Desktop\I"`

Then I got this error

```
$C = Get-ChildItem $P -Filter *.exe| Where-Object Name -Like '*r_2-2*' |  Sort-Object Name -Descending | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Skip 1 | Remove-Item

Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'D:\FM\r_2-2.exe' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:251
 + ... Descending | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Skip 1 | Remove-Item
```

I know about `foreach` loop but want to use `For-EachObject` cmdlet instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were quite close, if you want to use `ForEach-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem $P -Filter *.exe | Where-Object Name -Like '*r_2-2*' |  Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { remove-item $_.FullName -force }
```

To skip one first found result just `Select-Object -Skip 1` is enough.

`Remove-Item -Force` also removes hidden and read-only files.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the use of `FullName` parameter directly in your statement. Try this -

```
$C = Get-ChildItem $P -Filter *.exe| Where-Object Name -Like '*r_2-2*' |  Sort-Object Name -Descending | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName -Skip 1
$c | ForEach-Object {Remove-Item -Path $_}
```

Use `-Force` parameter if you want to delete the hidden files too.